# QueryParser.parse, restrict the distance between words

Tags: python, python-3.x, whoosh, fuzzy

I am using whoosh package to do full-text fuzzy match.

My current code is as follows:

```
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *
from whoosh.query import FuzzyTerm


class MyFuzzyTerm(FuzzyTerm):
    def __init__(self, fieldname, text, boost=1.0, maxdist=2, prefixlength=1, constantscore=True):
        super(MyFuzzyTerm, self).__init__(fieldname, text, boost, maxdist, prefixlength, constantscore)


if not os.path.exists("indexdir"):
    os.mkdir("indexdir")

path = u"MMM2.txt"
content = open('MMM2.txt', 'r').read()

schema = Schema(name=TEXT(stored=True), content=TEXT)
ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
writer = ix.writer()
writer.add_document(name=path, content= content)
writer.commit()

from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser, FuzzyTermPlugin, PhrasePlugin, SequencePlugin

with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    parser = QueryParser(u"content", ix.schema,termclass = MyFuzzyTerm)
    parser.add_plugin(FuzzyTermPlugin())
    parser.remove_plugin_class(PhrasePlugin)
    parser.add_plugin(SequencePlugin())
    str = u"Tennessee Riverkeeper Inc"
    query = parser.parse(str)
    # query = parser.parse(u"\"Tennessee Riverkeeper Inc\"~")
    results = searcher.search(query)
    print ("nb of results =", len(results),results, type(results))
    for r in results:
        print (r)
```

In document MMM2.txt, it contains the following text: "Tennessee aa  Riverkeeper aa aa Inc".  Ideally, I want the program returns 0 as I want to restrict the distance among the words in my term within 1. However, it still returns:

```
nb of results = 1 <Top 1 Results for And([MyFuzzyTerm('content', 'tennessee', boost=1.000000, maxdist=2, prefixlength=1), MyFuzzyTerm('content', 'riverkeeper', boost=1.000000, maxdist=2, prefixlength=1), MyFuzzyTerm('content', 'inc', boost=1.000000, maxdist=2, prefixlength=1)]) runtime=0.009658594451408662> <class 'whoosh.searching.Results'>
<Hit {'name': 'MMM2.txt'}>
```

However, if I replace:

```
query = parser.parse(str)
```

with:

```
query = parser.parse(u"\"Tennessee Riverkeeper Inc\"~")
```

It worked as I wanted to return non-matching results.  I guess it has something to do with "~". But I cannot add it when I replace the string the variable name. Since I have so many strings to be matched, I cannot type them one by one. I can only store them into variables each time in the loop.  Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it:

just change:

```
query = parser.parse('"%s"~' % str)
```

Hope it can help someone!